# Python Pandas and Spearmanr rowwise run faster

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to take two dataframes and run row wise spearmanr correlation. I've set the code up so it runs but it is taking a very long time, and I was hoping that there is a better/faster way to run this out there. The tables look something like this:

df1 (50x14492):

```
TYPE GENRE1 GENRE2
Name1 .0945 .0845
Name2 .9074 Nan
Name3 1     0
```

and df2 (50x14492):

```
TYPE GENRE1 GENRE2
Name1 .9045 .895
Name2 .074  1
Name3 .5    .045
```

And I'd like to get the correlation information for df1.Name1 and df2.Name2, so I'd have a dictionary that says {Name1:corr, Name2:corr2} so I have the following code.

```
for df1_row in df1.itertuples():
    for df2_row in df2.itertuples():
        if df2_row.TYPE.upper() == df1_row.TYPE.upper():
            df1_val_array = list(df1_row)
            df2_val_array = list(df2_row)
            df1_val_array = df1_val_array[2:]
            df2_val_array = df2_val_array[2:]
            df1_df2_gene_corr, df1_df2_gene_p_val = scipy.stats.spearmanr(df1_val_array, df2_val_array, axis=0, nan_policy='omit')
            correlation_dict[df2_row.TYPE.upper()] = df1_df2_gene_corr

# plot correlations
plt.plot(list(correlation_dict.keys()), correlation_dict.values())
plt.show()
```

Is there anyway to do this that doesn't take forever, due to the data length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try this:

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr as spr

df1 = df1.set_index('TYPE')
df2 = df2.set_index('TYPE')

df1, df2 = df1.align(df2)

def scorr(t):
  return spr(*t, axis=0, nan_policy='omit').correlation

pd.Series([*map(scorr, zip(df1.values, df2.values))], df1.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could you perhaps explain a little more about each step here? I believe you change the index to TYPE so that the rows and columns are flipped and then ensure that df1 and df2 are in the same order with align? After that you zip the two dataframes and pass them to scorr(t)? What's the *map part for?

Comment: I need you to provide a slightly bigger example and what you expect the results to be.  Before that, I can't be certain what I'm doing is even correct.  And that would be a waste of time.  Let me know when you edit your post with that information.